# SQL join by combination of ID and date range

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join

There are to tables - assignments and countries.

Assignments stores historical data about employees historical assignments, and the three main fields are - person_id, effective_start_date and effective_end_date.

Countries stores info about employees who have been taking trips abroad - the important fields in it are person_id, date_from, date_to, home_country, host_country.

And i need to do the following : I need to show all assignments, and the country which the employee had been to at any point during the assignment. Which means i need to join them via outer join, but the only way i can join them is via person_id but there are multiple entries in each table (Same ID's)

[image]
So what i did was something like this :

```
select * 
from assignments ass, employees emp
where
ass.person_id=emp.person_id
AND (emp.date_from(+) >= ass.assignment_start_date AND emp.date_to(+) <= ass.assignment_end_date)
OR (emp.date_from(+) >= ass.assignment_start_date AND emp.date_to(+) >= ass.assignment_end_date)
```

but it doesnt work because oracle doesn't allow me to make OR statement in an outer join. I tried using union all method but the values returned are not what i quite expected - there are some missing values, so the logic isn't correct eighter. If you have any advices please post them in the same syntax i provided (oracle syntax) where joins are made in where clause, so it's easier for me to understand.

Comment: What is `dah` in your query? Also, in your question, you mention a `countries` table - is this really the `employees` table? And finally, why don't you have a filter on `employee.date_to` in your query?

Comment: Edited some mistakes, my head is a mess today. I'm new here and everything here seems so complicated for me.

Comment: Don't worry, SO (StackOverflow) is pretty straightforward once you get used to it :-)

Comment: Regarding your edit: I can only speak for myself, but I will not use Oracle syntax even if you ask for it (because it's unreadable, outdated and shouldn't be used in new code at all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your desired result, you can use the following approach:

- use ANSI style JOINs instead of the outdated Oracle syntax (they're much more flexible and IMHO also more readable)
- concatenate the countries (e.g. using `LISTAGG`)

Query:

```
select ass.person_id, 
       assignment_start_date, 
       assignment_end_date,   
       listagg(home_country ||'-' || host_country, ';')
          within group (order by date_from) as countries
  from assignments ass
  left join employees emp
    on ass.person_id = emp.person_id
   AND ((emp.date_from >= ass.assignment_start_date AND
       emp.date_from <= ass.assignment_end_date)
    OR (emp.date_to >= ass.assignment_start_date AND
       emp.date_to <= ass.assignment_end_date))
group by ass.person_id, assignment_start_date, assignment_end_date
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/1517)

Answer (score 0):

I think is this what you want, with oracle syntax

```
select ass.person_id, assignment_start_date, assignment_end_date, 
emp.home_country,emp.host_country
from assignments ass, employees emp
where
ass.person_id=emp.person_id(+)
AND (emp.date_from(+) <= ass.assignment_end_date AND emp.date_to(+) >= ass.assignment_end_date)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0d697/7)

Comment: It's close to what i need, but this won't work in cases when assignment_start_date < date_from and assignment_end_date > date_to

Comment: I think what you want is that assignment_end_date is between date_from and date_end. Can the dates in assignments table for the same person overlap?or can the dates in the employee table overlap?

Comment: The logic is following : if at any point during the assignment employee was in a different country then i need to show the colums from employee table. Also, during 1 assignment employee will never travel to 2 different countries.

Comment: So have you figured this out?